# How to replace words automaticly on PHP

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have a table on mysql database like this :

```
|word|replace|
--------------
|sa  | sap   |
|ri  | sip   |
|na  | sup   |
--------------
```

So, if I submit the word : `sarina`, it will automatic change : `sapsipsup`

I've tried like this :

```
$word= array("sa", "ri", "na");
$replace = array("sap", "sip", "sup");

$str = str_split("sarina",2);
$result = str_replace($word, $replace, $str);
echo $result;
```

But, it's not dynamic, i mean.. i should split "sarina" to 2 chars first.
How to make it simple automaticly for any words?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see that code that goes with the word => replace

Comment: yes, sir. I want to make it replace automaticly

Comment: What have you tried? What is your problem? Connecting to the table? Querying its content? Extracting its content? Calling `str_replace`? You have to be more specific.

Comment: Maybe the OP made a mistake on his question because he says that sarina is transform to sapsipsip when in fact, it should be transformed into sapsipsup. My question is, does he currently have code that does the conversion, or did he simply mess up when giving the conversion and is asking for code....

Comment: sorry, sir, i've changed my question above. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically answered yourself by tagging your question `str-replace`. All you need to do is query all entries from your database, put them into two arrays and run `str_replace()` on your string using these two arrays. Something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT `word`, `replace` FROM `table`');
$find = array();
$replace = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $find[] = $row['word'];
   $replace[] = $row['replace'];
}
$yourstring = str_replace($find, $replace, $yourstring);
```

*Note: There is no error handling etc. in here...don't use that code as it is, only as inspiration.*

Comment: `$row['find']` should be `$row['word']`

Comment: and how if, i input "sana", is it automaticly changed to "sapsup" ? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...the code should do exactly that.